Django modeltranslation not working properly on templates
I have set up and configured django-modeltranslation for a project according to the documentation as follows:
urls.py
from django.conf.urls.i18n import set_language
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    ...
    path('set_language/', set_language, name='set_language'),
)

settings.py
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'modeltranslation',
    ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]

TIME_ZONE = 'CET'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('cz', _('Czech')),
]

LOCALE_PATHS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'Project/locale/',
]

USE_I18N = True

Homepage language switcher
<form id="languageForm" action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ request.get_full_path|slice:'3:' }}" />
    <input id="languageInput" name="language" type="hidden" value="" />
</form>

onclick="setLanguage('en')"
onclick="setLanguage('cz')"

function setLanguage(lang) {
    document.getElementById('languageInput').value = lang;
    document.getElementById('languageForm').submit();
}

In .html templates
{% load i18n %}

...
{% trans "Text" %}
...

I collected the strings for translation using:
python manage.py makemessages -l cz

Then translated them in the locale django.po file and compiled them using:
python manage.py compilemessages

Now when running the project and switching the language to cz, only one translated string and date strings are displayed.
Thank you for your help, and I hope I provided everything needed.
I tried setting up the django-modeltranslation using its documentation as I provided before.
EDIT: Figured out the problem was in the language code name, it was supposed to be CS instead of CZ
